# How to configure PEAR in server

Tags: php, apache, ini, php-ini

I'm using `Batavi` to build an online store, and when I install it is giving error like

> PEAR is not installed on this server or path to a directory with PEAR is not specified in the include_path.

and another error like 
Version of Apache on your server has been hidden.

I don't have any idea how to set it up, may be with `php.ini` file, can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your operating system probably there should be a pear package.

For example on ubuntu linux it is `php-pear`, and you can install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

If pear is only missing from your include_path, you should add it in your php.ini files. (somewhere around /etc/php*)

In my case `/etc/php5/*/php.ini`:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
```

But you should verify the path.

Comment: PEAR is alreay installed, but seems it is mis-configured or some path issues in that

Comment: @PetersonAndrew try reinstalling

Comment: I added to my answer a few hint about configuring include_path.